# Why my second div acts like it would have a margin-top set up?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs set up with

```
display: inline-block.
```

I don't know why but the second div always slides a little bit down in comparision to the first

```
div
```

just like it would have a margin-top set up. How to make the second div fully inline with the first div and how to position the

```
<ul>
```

vertically and horizontally in the center of the second div ?

Here is Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJhBK

The borders are not intended in the final project. I've placed them to visually show the position of each divs.

Thanks !

Comment: Use `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav {
width: 446px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align:top
}
```

add the alignment this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I'll try that right now.

Comment: Is it correct if then I add position:absolute to my <ul> and try to position it in middle of the nav container ? Or is there a better way ?

Comment: @Danny_Student You can. I would use `position: relative;` on the parent container (`<div id="nav">`) so that the `<ul>` is positioned absolutely relative to the `#nav` instead of absolute to the document.

Comment: Owkie dowkie. Btw. just wondering - why the area of the nav element expanded when i have added margin-top to the <ul> element ? I thought that such a thing happens only if I would add a padding.

Answer (score 0):

remove `display: inline-block;` and use `float:left`

Comment: But on what element ? First div which is 'logo' or 'nav' ? And do I need to do so-called 'clearing floats' after that ? Thanks

Comment: put it on the #nav element, you don't need to do clearing floats

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've already used the method proposed by @Mathijs Segers